# Can a TCP 3-way handshake be aborted with the POSIX socket interface?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, posix

I'm working on a load balancer probe engine that sends probe requests to servers to determine their availability.
The probe configuration has a TCP-only setting where server availability is detected by setting up a TCP connection followed by a disconnect.

The disconnect *can* be a TCP RST (depending on the load balancer setup), which makes the probe request look like:

```
load balancer                server
                 SYN ->
              <- SYN/ACK
                 ACK ->
                 RST ->
```

The 3rd ACK seems unnecessary since the connection is not going to be used to exchange data.
Also, it might be easier on the server if it only received a RST. 
In that case, the server has to handle a socket (`accept`) error instead of dealing with the overhead of a new connection (e.g. creating a thread).

I can abort an established connection by setting the linger time zero (`setsockopt`), but in this case I am interested in sending a RST before the connection is established.

Can the the Posix socket interface support the following TCP exchange ?

```
load balancer                server
                 SYN ->
              <- SYN/ACK
                 RST ->
```

Comment: [`accept()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) can fail with `errno == ECONNABORTED`, yes (for both cases; whenever RST arrives sooner than the kernel manages to service the accept() call, regardless of whether an ACK comes first or not). I believe, but have not verified (and that's why this is a comment and not an answer) that all TCP/IP stacks used in POSIXy systems do support that.

Comment: Probably you would have to use RAW sockets and craft your own SYN packets and send RST instead of SYN when you receive a valid SYN/ACK.